# Paginate related models

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I would like to paginate 2 models: `Trip` which `hasMany` `PartialTrip`.

The `Trip` model:

```
public function PartialTrips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PartialTrip', 'main_trip_id');
}
```

The tricky part is that, in the object that contains the queried information, I want to have each `PartialTrip` under the `Trip` that owns it. So, f.e.: query `Trip` -> query `PartialTrip` with `whereMainTripId` = the id of the current `Trip` -> paginate(5).

This way, when I list them, the partial trips will not be at the end of the array object, but each of them will be directly after its parent trip.

**Update**

I am doing this (just as a test to see whether the `::with('PartialTrips')` works:

```
            $trips = Trip::with('PartialTrips')
                ->select('id', 'driver_user_id', 'route_from', 'route_to', 'start_date')
                ->get();
            var_dump(count($trips));
```

and it returns me the just the number of the `Trip`s that I have (I counted how many *trips* and *partial trips* I have in the DB).

`->toSql()` on that query yields me the following:

```
"select 'id', 'driver_user_id', 'route_from', 'route_to', 'start_date' from 'trips'"
```

so I guess the `::with('PartialTrips')` does not really work in this case...

Comment: You have done the relationship between `Trip` and `PartialTrip` inside `Trip model` already, right?

Comment: `Eager load` might help, `$trips = Trip::with('partialTrips')->paginate(5);`

Comment: @mininoz , I updated my post. Can you check it out, please?

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer where `trip_id` come from

> Take note that Eloquent assumes the foreign key of the relationship
>   based on the model name.

more detail: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-one

When you are using  `hasMany` relationship `without specific foreign` key, the model is assume to use `trip_id` as a foreign key (table name + id). Anyway you can overwrite it. And you model might look like

```
//Trip model
public function PartialTrips()
{
    return $this->hasMany('PartialTrip', 'main_trip_id'); // second parameter is your foreign key
}
```

more details: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#one-to-many

And you can get all the `trips` with `partial trips` by passing `$trips` variable to your view and render them like this

```
@foreach ($trips as $trip)
  <div> Your trip id: {{ $trip->id }}</div>
  <div> -- Partial Trips </div>
  @foreach ($trip->partialTrips as $partialTrip)
    <div> Partial trip id: {{ $partialTrip->id }}</div>
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Note: when you are using `with()` (eager loading), `$partialTrips` will be nested inside `$trips`. That why you get only number of $trips when using count($trips). But you can get partialTrips by using code above.

source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: I have made that, but in the `PartialTrip` model with the `belongsTo` method... I guess that was the wrong place... :D

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to tell you where to place the code. You need to put  it in `Trip model`. Do you get it works?

Comment: No, it does not yield me data from the PartialTrip entity... :(

Comment: Would you please update your question with the view where you loop the `$trips`?

Comment: I updated my answer. note: I changed  `function PartialTrip()` to `function PartialTrips()`.

Comment: Yeah, I also changed it to `PartialTrips`, but the problem is different - look what SQL syntax yields me when I print out the query with `toSql()`... the PartialTrip entitiy is not included in the query at all...